# How to make this counter section in my website responsive?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am a new web designer and I am struggling right now in designing a responsive counter section which shows the number of happy clients, line of codes and so on.

Here's my **HTML Code:**

```
 <section id="call-to-action-2" class="section-padding">
        <div data-velocity="-.3" class="overlay-bg cta-bg"></div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <div class="counter-item">
                        <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>
                        <div class="timer" id="item1" data-to="991" data-speed="5000"></div>
                        <h5>Training Courses</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <div class="counter-item">
                        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                        <div class="timer" id="item2" data-to="7394" data-speed="5000"></div>
                        <h5>Affiliates</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <div class="counter-item">
                        <i class="fa fa-code"></i>
                        <div class="timer" id="item3" data-to="18745" data-speed="5000"></div>
                        <h5>Accreditations</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <div class="counter-item">
                        <i class="fa fa-male"></i>
                        <div class="timer" id="item4" data-to="8423" data-speed="5000"></div>
                        <h5>Happy clients</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
.counter-item {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

    .counter-item h5 {
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .counter-item i {
        font-size: 40px;
    }


.timer {
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 80px;
}
```

Here's the link to JSFiddle that includes all of the previous code with the external resources: https://jsfiddle.net/bjwroqym/
I just wanna make space between each timer in the below snapshot:

[image]

The expected result of this code for a desktop or iPad screen size is very well and nice.

[image]

However, for the mobile screen size is not displayed properly and I don't know why. **Could you please tell me how to fix this design issue?**

**UPDATE:**

I tried what @Georgie suggested to me, and I got the following result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have created any mdedia queries for this. Anyway see if this one works for you.
I have added a pretty basic media query and called the .timer and gave it extra margin-bottom.

```
 <section id="call-to-action-2" class="section-padding">
    <div data-velocity="-.3" class="overlay-bg cta-bg"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                <div class="counter-item">
                    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>
                    <div class="timer" id="item1" data-to="991" data-speed="5000"></div>
                    <h5>Training Courses</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                <div class="counter-item">
                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                    <div class="timer" id="item2" data-to="7394" data-speed="5000"></div>
                    <h5>Affiliates</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                <div class="counter-item">
                    <i class="fa fa-code"></i>
                    <div class="timer" id="item3" data-to="18745" data-speed="5000"></div>
                    <h5>Accreditations</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                <div class="counter-item">
                    <i class="fa fa-male"></i>
                    <div class="timer" id="item4" data-to="8423" data-speed="5000"></div>
                    <h5>Happy clients</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>





    .counter-item {
         position: relative;
         text-align: center;
          }
    .counter-item h5 {
      text-align: center;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
     }

    .counter-item i {
     font-size: 40px;
    }


   .timer {
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 80px;

    }

 /* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
    @media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
      .timer {
        margin-bottom:40px;
         }
     }
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but your way did not add space between each timer section. I just updated my question, so would you kindly have a look at it and tell me what I should do?

Comment: Hi again, sorry for the late response.
Could you try and add the double margin? make it
.margin-bottom:80px;
in general play around with it. If it won't work let me know so we can figure out something else.